# How to find the center of mass from CapsuleCast in unity

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics, mathematics, geometry

Is there an easy way to find the center of mass from a CapsuleCast, or should I find the geometric center of it?

Comment: The center of mass of a capsule, like any symmetrical object, assuming uniform density, can *only* be its geometric center. But a CapsuleCast is not an object with mass at all, it is the *process" of finding another object, so it's questionable what "center of mass" would even mean in that case. Can you walk us through how you're using this in your game? This can help clear up any confusion and ensure you get an answer appropriate to your use case.

Comment: I'm trying to make my own physics system in unity. I was asking if there was a function that gave you the centroid of the CapsuleCast or would I have to do that manually.

Comment: A CapsuleCast is a movement of a capsule-shaped region as it sweeps along a line, so it's not immediately clear whether you mean the centroid of the capsule at a particular point in that movement, or the centroid of the swept region. Can you edit your question to make this unambiguous? I think in any case the answer is calculate it yourself, but we can show you the calculation once we know what you want.